# How to properly install facebook-php-sdk into joomla project?

Tags: php, joomla, facebook-php-sdk

I am currently working on a Joomla project, and I was assigned to integrate Facebook login in the project. But I am stuck because I am not sure how to properly install facebook-php-sdk into the project. I have tried to install it in the project directory that I stored in htdoc using composer and the installation was successful. But when I open up the web page, then I got the following error:

> Warning:
>   require_once(//includes/vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\home\opencom\public_html\tmp\sourcerer_php_ea54a6300345426cd42587b0e16e0749
>   on line 10
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '//includes/vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\home\opencom\public_html\tmp\sourcerer_php_ea54a6300345426cd42587b0e16e0749
>   on line 10

Is there any easier way or proper way to do this?

Comment: You may like to ask the dedicated Joomla audience at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Why does the path start with `//includes`? The double slash is out of place, and do you really have the `includes` folder at the very root of your file system …?